# Connection String Help Microsoft Jet 4.0 Paradox

Tags: database-connection, powerpivot, jet, paradox

I am trying to connect to a server in PowerPivot.  I am running across a few problems.  Here is the connection string:

**Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\accounting001\Accounting\TimeSlips2014\Databases\Philadelphia\;Extended Properties=Paradox 5.x.**

It uses NT authentication as the password.  I have read all about the problems with MS Jet 4.0.  I am running 64x on 64x office apps.  I receive the not registered on local computer error.  Can anyone help me connect.  I already installed the Access 2010 DB engine however I wasn't able to get it to connect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Jet and the Jet ODBC driver are available in 32-bit versions only. You can't run them in 64 bit mode.

**The Solution**
If you run a program in a 64 bit environment and need to utilize jet to open an Access, Excel or text file there are several options to make this work.

Run the program in WoW64 mode (emulates 32-bit on 64 bit systems). This will make the 32 bit drivers work.

If the application is an web app hosted on IIS 7 you can choose to configure the web sites application pool to run in 32-bit mode.

With Office 2010, there are new drivers, the 2010 Office System Driver, which will be provided in both 32-bit and 64-bit versions. You can use these drivers to let your application connect to Access, Excel and text files in a 64 bit environment utilizing the new 64-bit drivers. The provider name is "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0". You don't need to buy or install the Office suite, the components are available as a separate download. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en

**Summary**
It is possible to open Excel, Access and text files on 64 bit systems. You can either configure your app to go 32-bit or you can change your application to use the new 64 bit drivers.

See the original link for this information [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/).

Comment: So its paradox and I know this is only supported in a 32bit driver.  My environment is 64 bit and my Office 2013 app is 64 bit.  I am trying to connect to a program called Sage TimeSlips into my Excel PowerPivot.  Are there any other solutions?